# Best way to import and extend a class in ES6

Tags: node.js, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I want to create a class in one file, import and extend it in another. Something like:

```
/* someclass.js */
    export class SomeClass {}

/* somesubclass.js */
        import SomeClass from './someclass'
        class SomeSubClass extends SomeClass {}
```

Is it possible or is there any better way to do this (e.g. using node.js `module.exports`)?

Comment: You'll probably want to `export` the `SomeSubClass` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example is almost correct. You can export your class as default:

```
export default class SomeClass {}
// and then import
import SomeClass from './someclass';
class SomeSubClass extends SomeClass {}
```

or use named export:

```
export class SomeClass {}
// and then import
import { SomeClass } from './someclass';
class SomeSubClass extends SomeClass {}
```

See [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) syntax on MDN.